# partition by customer for distinct items

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

[image]

select customer_id,
row_number()over(partition by customer id
order by date) as rn
from table

[image]

How to get same rn when Item Id is the same?

Below did not work:
#1 select customer_id,
row_number()over(partition by customer id, Item Id
order by date) as rn
from table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try to use [`DENSE_RANK`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_DENSE_RANK.html) instead of `row_number` window function

> If the optional PARTITION BY clause is present, the rankings are reset for each group of rows. Rows with equal values for the ranking criteria receive the same rank

```
select customer_id, DENSE_RANK() over(partition by customer id order by date) as rn 
from table
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.                                                                                                  
order by item_id worked.                                                         
order by date reset the rn for every new date.                                                                                                    
select customer_id, DENSE_RANK() over(partition by customer id order by item_id) as rn 
from table